# Python - Compare stdout of cmd against a hard coded list and print the individual matches, making each a different variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to run a command (driverquery) via a python script and compare the stdout against a predefined list that is hard coded into the script. If a match is found, it would print the match and also make it a unique variable for later in the script.  If multiple matches were found, each finding would be printed and be a unique variable.

Right now I am only able to compare the stdout against the hard coded values and determine if their is a match or not (yes/no).

```
import subprocess


def checkdrivers():
    cmd = "driverquery"
    p = subprocess.run(cmd, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=True)
    output = p.stdout
    print("Command output: ", output)

    value = {'smbdirect', 'Tcpip', 'VBoxDrv', 'xboxgip'}

    check = any(item in output for item in value)

    if check is True:
        print("Yes, drivers exist.")
    else:
        print("No, drivers DO NOT exist.")


checkdrivers()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way:

```
matches = []

for item in output:
    if item in value:
        matches.append(item)
        print('driver', item, 'matches')
...
```

The fancier way

```
matches = set(output).union(value)
print(matches)
```

Also maybe rename variables to be more descriptive, so "value" becomes "expected_drivers" or something like that.

```
def checkdrivers():
    cmd = "driverquery"
    output = subprocess.run(cmd, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=True).stdout

    print("Command output: ", output)

    expected_drivers = {'smbdirect', 'Tcpip', 'VBoxDrv', 'xboxgip'}
    found_drivers = expected_drivers.union(set(output))
    print('found:', found_drivers)

    ...
```